# C# program calling C++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a dll file and it's corresponding .h file.
I want to call it from a C# program.
I suspect this is either impossible or very difficult.

Here is a portion of the .h File which I want to use

```
    int SelfTest();

    /******************************************************
     * C++ functions
    ******************************************************/
    int CPP_Init(std::string baseDirectory);
    std::vector<std::string> CPP_GetKeys();
    std::string CPP_ProcessData(std::string plaintext,
                            std::string keyName,
                            std::string sourceStation,
                            std::string destinationStation,
                            int encryptData,
                            int extendedChecksumHeader);
    std::vector<std::string> CPP_Decrypt(std::string cipherText);
```

Comment: Call it how? Via COM? Via a DLL import? What have you already tried?

Comment: Rank that one under "impossible".  It requires a C++/CLI wrapper to properly handle the std:string and std:;vector templates.

Comment: Martin, I will call it anyway you recommend.  I have not tried anything.  I have spent a few hours searching the internet for an answer, and I suspect it is just not possible.

Comment: See here for a answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53179999/3346583

Comment: Christopher - if I do #1 in that list, and just add the dll as a project reference.  I suspect there will still be problems with the functions' strings and vectors?

Comment: I have an idea.  What if I write a C++ DLL which calls this dll, and thereby provide easier data types for the arguments and the function return values?  What will be easiest?  Array of char?

Comment: Oh my.  I can't even add the dll file as a reference.  It says "...could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."  This dll was probably made by QT.  I might just have to abandon using it.

Answer (score 0):

(**note**, if you don't want to read the whole thing here, probably you'll want to have a look at [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425202/is-it-possible-to-call-a-c-function-from-c-net).)

First of all, I'll try to conduct this answer from the historical perspective, as you are asking a need that comes with time, but original design of neither C++ nor C# was to make them compatible languages.  I shall involve C in the middle, as the design requirement of C++ to be compatible with C made a lot of design decisions on it to solve the problem (and this will make a lot of light on the subject).  As such, it is the only language design on which source (and not binary) compatibility has been an original requirement.  There are two reasons to follow this approach:

- C# was designed later than C++, so if any of these has some compatibility properties in its design, it is probable that C# has them, as C++ had no binary compatibility design decisions made to C# (it didn't exist at the time of C++ definition)
- As C++ was designed with *"compatibility"* requirements in mind, to be able to use the vast set of library routines available from C, it is a language that has some way to *express* this compatibility statements somehow, so it is possible to have some point of reference that allows you to search for, in the documentation.

Compiling a C program with a C compiler has some drawbacks when talking about interfacing C and C++ routines between each other.  When C++ was designed, it was with *C compatibility in mind.*  But the opposite is not true, nobody designed C with *"being C++ compatible"* in mind.  The  only way to be able to access C++ functions from C is to compile those with a C++ compiler and do the *compatibility* modifications to deal with the intrinsic incompatibilities of both languages (or use a C compiler, and then link the binaries together using a C++ linker) This last point is very important **link them with a C++ linker** (or to link in C++ mode)

Why is so important to use a C++ linker to link C and C++ objects together?   Mainly because the C linker is not prepared to include the needs of the C++ language (global objects instantiation, calling their constructors, is not supported by the C linker)  In the case of Java or C++, the object instances are always (at least in Java, cannot assure what happens in C#) managed by reference.  C# was designed as a language for the .Net virtual machine specification (as Sun did also with Java) and as you have C++ compilers for that platform also, C++ was designed not thinking on a virtual target platform, and probably the possibility of such an arrangment of using C++ from C# will be at least difficult.

Let's talk about the C/C++ case:

First, for the C++ functions to be reachable from the C code, they must have `"C"` calling interface  (it is possible that some *language extension* is neccessary to make C++ method calls and functions compatible with C#).  This means the C++ functions you'll call from C need to be declared as

```
extern "C" void my_cplusplus_function(type1 arg1, type2 arg2);
```

or put all in a

```
extern "C" {
    ...
}
```

block.  The reason for this is that C++ compilers *mangle external identifiers* (including parameter types and other function attributes, as the `const` attribute on methods...) to allow different versions for the same function name with different interfaces, and this is not compatible with the C calling interface.  Of course, this is also true for C#  (perhaps there's some `extern "C#"` extension in Visual C++ compiler to make name mangling work with C# language definitions).  If you don't follow this approach, the first thing you have is to check which one of the possible definitions with that name is the one you want, then check how the compiler *mangles* the complete prototype definition to know the final name the linker gets and is used to access the function, and finally, to respect the complete environment of stack frames, function activation records, etc. that will make the program to hang if not followed.  If you have interest on the Java/C++ way (full documented in www.java.com) you'll see the limitations imposed by Java/C++ function calls (it is document under the epigraph *JNI*, probably if you look for a **C sharp native interface**, you'll get something)  That is due to the different memory organisations of executables, even for the same target platform.

An example of the *"C compatibility mode"* (sorry, I don't have an equivalent for C# or Java at hand) will illustrate this:

## main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* for printf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for EXIT_SUCCESS */
#include <math.h>   /* for normal sqrt() */

#include "cpp_sqrt.h"  /* for the prototype of cpp_mysqrt() */

int main()
{
    /* you are forced to use stdio here, as you are in plain C */
    printf("cpp_sqrt(3.0) => %lg\n"
           "sqrt(3.0)     => %lg\n",
           cpp_sqrt(3.0), /* <== this is a c++ function */
           sqrt(3.0));    /* <== this is the math C function */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

## cpp_mysqrt.cc

```
#include "cpp_sqrt.h"
#include <iostream>

double cpp_sqrt(const double x)
{
    /* you can use all C++ stuff here, as this is C++ */
    std::cout << "in cpp_sqrt()" << std::endl;

    double     g = 1.0, /* geometric mean */
               a = x;   /* arithmetic mean */
    const double epsilon = 1.0E-6;

    while ((a - g) > epsilon) {
            a = (a + g) / 2.0;
            g = x / a;
    }

    return g;
}
```

## cpp_mysqrt.h

```
/* this construction is required to be able to include this
 * file in C and C++ source code.  C++ compilers always define
 * the __cplusplus macro, so they will include the
 * extern "C" block, while C compilers don't.  This makes it
 * possible to use the same prototype header file in both C and
 * C++ source files without problems.
 */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

double cpp_sqrt(double X);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} /* extern "C" */
#endif
```

If you erase the `extern "C" {`  and `}` parts of the header file (or simply rename `__cplusplus` to `__cplusplus1` for C++ compiler not to use it), the C++ compiler will mangle the name for the `cpp_sqrt(double)` function, making it unreachable from C code, as you'll see if you try to compile it:

```
$ ed cpp_sqrt.h <<'EOF'
1,$s/__cplusplus/__cplusplus1/g
w
EOF
$ make
cc -O -pipe -c main.c -o main.o
c++ -O -pipe -c cpp_sqrt.cc -o cpp_sqrt.o
c++  -o cppfromc main.o cpp_sqrt.o -lm
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `cpp_sqrt'
c++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /home/user/cfromcpp
```

So finally, how is the problem you have solved in modern times?  The developer that faces such a problem normally builds an *"interface set of functions"* that comply with the interface restrictions for both worlds and acts as *glue code* (sure, you have heard that last term) to make the interface possible.  This makes it possible to have Java access raw sockets, or access lowlevel operating system functionality.

It also makes it possible that, if your library interface changes in the future, you only have to change the *glue module* to make it work again with the new version.

## Note

Next is the `Makefile` used to build the sample code, just execute `make` to build the program:

## Makefile

```
RM ?= rm -f

targets = cppfromc
toclean=$(targets)

cppfromc_objs = main.o cpp_sqrt.o
toclean += $(cppfromc_objs)
cppfromc_libs = -lm

all: $(targets)
clean:
    $(RM) $(toclean)

# NOTE: you must use the C++ linker because C++ programs have a different memory map,
# to allow for constructors of global object instances to be constructed before main()
# is executed.
cppfromc: main.o cpp_sqrt.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $($@_objs) $($@_libs)

main.o cpp_sqrt.o: cpp_sqrt.h
```